# On iOS 10.1.1 discoverServices not working or error CoreBluetooth[ERROR] XPC connection interrupted, resetting occurs after call to discoverServices

Tags: ios, swift

On iOS 10.1.1 discoverServices not working or error CoreBluetooth[ERROR] XPC connection interrupted, resetting  occurs after  call to discoverServices , or it gets immediatelly disconnected

I have iOS device that is central and other device Android based, that is peripheral. I scan for peripherals, then after user select device , call for connect peripheral  and in didConnect call for discoverServices. But then problem happens. Tested same code on earlier iOS versions like  (9.3 and 10.1 works without  any problems 10/10 times). What could be a problem. On iOS 10.1.1 it succeeds every few times,but usually there is a problem

Here is code:

Everything is in separate mananger for Bluetooth communication
First I discover peripherals and put in in  array:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,advertisementData: [String : Any],rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
}
```

Via delegate  I put names in tableView, and when user selects peripheral I take choosen peripheral from peripherals array and call:

```
func connect(_ peripheral:CBPeripheral) {
        self.peripheralToConnect = peripheral
        peripheral.delegate = self
        if let manager = centralManager, manager.state == .poweredOn{
            if (peripheral.state == .connected){
                manager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
            }
            if manager.isScanning {
                manager.stopScan()
            }
            manager.connect(peripheral, options:nil)
        }
    }


func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show us? A [MCVE]?

Comment: @purplepsycho Hi, I have edited question. Thank you! Also if it gets disconnected before didDiscoverServices this is error : Code=6 \"The connection has timed out unexpectedly.